# Override default cookbook chef variables

Tags: apache-spark, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am looking for specific instructions on how to override default values in a third party cookbook. For example, i am using `apache_spark` cookbook (https://github.com/clearstorydata-cookbooks/apache_spark)

And i want to override the attribute
`default['apache_spark']['standalone']['master_host']`

I tried it my making a main recipe, in which i add
`node.default['apache_spark']['standalone']['master_host'] = 'foo.com'`

And execute it using chef solo like:

```ruby
run_list(
  'recipe[main]',
  'recipe[apache_spark::spark-standalone-worker]'
)
```

But that does not seem to work. Any suggestions on how it needs to be done?
My main recipe is here https://github.com/Vibhuti/chef-main

Comment: Your `main::default` recipe seems to be empty and the cookbook has no `attributes/` directory. Is that right?

Comment: Actually they are empty thats why i guess git did not upload them.

Answer (score 6):

The correct fix would be to make a wrapper cookbook and set your values in the cookbook's attributes file (`main/attributes/default.rb`):

```
override['apache_spark']['standalone']['master_host'] = 'foo.com'
```

Also make sure you add a dependency in main's `metadata.rb` to force the load ordering to be correct:

```
depends 'apache_spark'
```

Comment: Thanks coderanger, seems fine approach. I will try doing this.

Comment: I usually stick to default in wrapper cookbooks for my company, and sometimes we have another cookbook which override the wrapper values for some snowflakes

Comment: When you understand the merge order more, then yeah. If you are new, the "big hammer" approach is usually safer.